# XML DTD creating tag with fixed text

Tags: xml, dtd

I do not know the basic in depth ...but I am trying to make a tag that print text automatically.This text in the tag is fixed.

I add the text in the attribute value ?? Is it right ??? so if I want to use the tag to print the fixed text in attribute will be   in xml like this :

This is my code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ex 
[
<!ELEMENT ex (#PCDATA)> 
<!ATTLIST  ex value CDATA #FIXED  "stack">

]>


<ex  />
```

Result :
it will printed : stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not really creating a tag (element) with fixed content, but you are creating an attribute with a fixed value.

Your XML instance, including DTD, is correct. This can be verified by using an XPath to display the value of the "value" attribute:

```
/ex/@value
```

However there isn't anything "automatic" about printing this value. That will have to be handled by whatever is processing the XML.

I don't think you can specify a default element value with DTD, but you can with an XML Schema. Read "[W3 - OccurrenceConstraints](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#OccurrenceConstraints)" for more details.

Comment: I see .. what about using Entity ? I am trying to write the code as : but it says error :<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE t
[
<!ELEMENT t (#PCDATA)> 
<!ENTITY c "xx">

]>



<t>&c;</t>

Comment: @Javalover - What error are you getting? That is also valid XML.

Comment: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Comment: @Javalover - Hmm...works ok for me. Check and make sure you don't have any whitespace before `<?Xxml...?>`

Comment: what editor do you use ? I am using Eclipse and Netbean ... it is the same Error!